# Resco: AdvancedList and PNG images

Tags: windows-mobile

When i use PNG images in my AdvancedList they are shown in very bad quality in the designer and when i deloy the project in the emulator the transparency disappears completely.

Is Resco not cabable of showing png images or what is the problem here?

Comment: Have you checked with Resco support?

Answer (score 0):

You should check Resco forum http://www.resco.net/forums/ShowForum.aspx?ForumID=24 or contact Resco support team resco.net/developer/support/form.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had just started using resco mobile toolkit on my project. Yes, the advancedlist supports transparency on images. Im not sure where your problems are but what i usually do is resize the images in an image editing software then I import it in rescoimagemanager and disable the autoresize in advancedlist. you may also want to verify the background of your png images on an image editing software.